# How to share text and link from android app to messenger?

Tags: android, facebook-messenger, android-sharing

I want to have possibility to share some text and link from my app to Messenger and get message like this:
(Message shared from Elephant Evolution app)

[image: Message shared from Elephant Evolution app]

This is my code:

```
                //SHARING TO FACEBOOK
            String photoURL = "https://play.google.com/";
            if(!mEvent.getPhotoUrl().isEmpty()){
                photoURL=mEvent.getPhotoUrl();
            }
            String quoteToShare = "someText";
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(photoURL))
                    .setQuote(quoteToShare)
                    .build();
            //ShareDialog.show(EventActivity.this,content);
            MessageDialog.show(EventActivity.this, content);
```

And with this code I am sharing only link:

[image]

When I am sharing the same "ShareLinkContent" to facebook, everything works good. Could anyone help me :) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can share text (and link) using `Intent` class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        String textToShare = "My own text\nhttps://stackoverflow.com/";

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            try {
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Package for Facebook Messenger is: `com.facebook.orca`

Comment: Thanks, Shoud I add to "sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);" to this intent?